# Is there a list of MPMoviePlayer error codes

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayer

if a movie finishes with an error, then I might get an error like:

> Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-12847 "This movie format is
>   not supported."

The same description is used for different error codes - but I can't find the code definitions anywhere.

Are they available?

Comment: have you looked in MPMoviePlayerViewController.h?

Comment: yes, nothing there. I have searched in the MediaPlayer framework folder too - nothing there.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_ErrorConstants/Reference/reference.html

God help you if your code (like mine) was -11800 (`AVErrorUnknown`).